# using angular script in loaded html page ( by ajax )

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, ajax

I have two HTML pages that include Jquery + Angularjs + some scripts.
when my first html loads the jquery script will load other html page by ajax, the second html page includes some angular script that doesn't work any more.

any solution? even if it needs to change the script of ajax that's no problem

check this [`project`](http://plnkr.co/edit/nh8vaqCPX3IIBl7TcWku)

Comment: **Jquery + Angularjs + some scripts**.... not helping at all. post the respective code snippets.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/nh8vaqCPX3IIBl7TcWku

Answer (score 0):

As you had given description I can suggest you only these things-

When you load the first html page, you have to load angular scripts within.

Because second html page is loaded by script then the second html page will not load angular scripts at that time.

You can add a .js file in which the script code will be there and this js file will include in first html page.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it the following way

Move the controller to `index.html`

In the body tag of the `index.html` add the app declaration

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
```

Inside the body tag include the reference to the `other.html`

```
 <div ng-include="'other.html'"></div>
```

In the other.html you only require the following code

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    Number {{yourName}}!
</div>
```

[**Plunker Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/UR0r22cVQW7TV4AuIV1L?p=preview)

Comment: I want to each external page has its script, if I use your way that you suggested the first page will load many scripts that may user doesn't need

Answer (score 0):

finally found what I want

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <p ng-bind-html="myText"></p>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http, $sce) {
    $http.get("page2.html").then(function (response) {
       $scope.myText = $sce.trustAsHtml(response.data);
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```